# Fatal Error Mediafallback.php on line 61

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, fatal-error

I am trying to add a configurable product on magento 1.9.1.0 and experiencing a fatal error

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php on line 61

Any suggestions how I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Faced same problem today, I fixed it by Overriding core files

1. Copy

   ```
   app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php
   ```

   to

   ```
   app/code/local/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php
   ```
2. and change line number 61 from

   ```
   $optionLabels += $attribute->getOptionLabels();
   ```

   to

   ```
   $optionLabels = array_merge($optionLabels, $attribute->getOptionLabels());
   ```

this will solve this error.

Answer (score -1):

replace this error line 61 : 
 $optionLabels .= $attribute->getOptionLabels();

i placed (.) instate of (+).
its working fine for me.

Comment: I would highly discourage editing Magento core files. IMO this is not a proper solution

Comment: Is this a core bug?  You wouldn't expect $attribute->getOptionLabels() to be a number, right? `.=` seems right? - although i would suggest moving the file to the local code pool.